# CREATE just reload the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to make my "create" from the form work.

In the inspect i dont get any messages just a page reload

Functions:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ nome: event.target.value });
}

handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post(url + "api/alunos" + this.state.aluno.nome)
        .then(res => {
            this.alunos.push({
                nome: this.aluno.nome,
            });
            this.aluno.nome = "";
            this.getUsers();
        });
}
```

HTML:

```
                <div>
                    <div onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>
                            Nome Aluno:
                         <input type="text" name="nome" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                        <button type="submit">Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

If you dont know the error but have a repo with a working CRUD helps me a lot.

Comment: You've used `onSubmit` on a `div` while it should be used on a `form`.

Comment: I did, im getting an error 405 probably in the axios.post line, http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/alunos/[object%20Object] 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: That's a new unrelated problem (to this question). You should first try to find the root cause, and if necessary ask a new question, complete with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Change your div tag to form tag

Comment: I did, im getting an error 405 probably in the axios.post line, http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/alunos/[object%20Object] 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Your front-end code is fine. You have to check the api